# While trying to ping, java.net.UnknownHostException gets thrown. I do not understand the reason

Tags: java, networking, ping, unknown-host

I wrote the following code to try a `ping`. But as I run it, the following exception gets thrown :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: http://localhost:8084/server/index.jsp
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:10)
```

---

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

class Tester {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("http://localhost:8084/server/index.jsp");
      boolean isReachable = address.isReachable(2000);
      if(isReachable)
        System.out.println("The address is reachable");
      else
        System.out.println("The address is not reachable");

    } catch(Exception exc) {
       exc.printStackTrace();
      }
}
}
```

Why is it so ? The server is running and the page is opening fine in the web-browser.

Comment: InetAddress.getByName("host") accept a host name and not his protocol. For example if your host is: "localhost:8084/server/abc/page.jsp" this  works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(
        "http://localhost:8084/server/index.jsp");
```

The `InetAddress.getByName(String)` method requires a hostname.  You've given it a URL string.  The hostname component of that address is `"localhost"`.

If you want to "ping" the host associated with a URL, then you need to parse the URL and extract the hostname component something like this:

```
String hostname = new URL(str).getHost();
```

But you need to deal with the cases where the URL is malformed, or where it doesn't have a host name component.

---

I imagine that you are *actually* trying to test some other hostname, because sending an ICMP_PING request to `"localhost"` (typically `127.0.0.1`) is kind of pointless.

Comment: The network address of this _localhost_ could look like : `http://192.168.43.187:8084/server/index.jsp` . How do the clients initially connected to the server, check again if they are connected to the server ? So I was trying to do this.

Comment: How do a client ping for the address : `http://192.168.43.187:8084/server/index.jsp ` ?

Comment: 1)  The name "localhost" is normally bound to a lookback address such as `127.0.0.1.  If it is bound to a non-loopback address, there is something a bit broken about your network configuration.  2) See the updates to my answer on how to extract the hostname from a URL.  3) Please STOP referring to a URL as an address.  It is a resource locator ... not an address.

Answer (score 0):

Because the domain behind a `firewall` which blocks the `ping` request

Comment: That wouldn't give an `UnknownHostException`.

Answer (score 0):

getByName take a host name, or IP addresse as parameter, not e URL.